# Not able to remove layer from map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using arcgis javascript api . I want to remove a recently added layer , i wrote like this

```
var a = map.layerIds;
var b = map.getLayer(a[2]);
map.removeLayer(b);
```

But I am not able to remove any layer.

Comment: are you refreshing after removing the layer ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for (var j = 0, k = map.layerIds.length; j < k; j++) {
    var currentLayer = map.getLayer(map.layerIds[j]);
    if (currentLayer.id == "yourLayerID") {
        map.removeLayer(currentLayer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code should work. I'm guessing you don't have the right index of your `a` variable. Here's a jsfiddle showing your code working (click the "remove" button to run your code and see the layer get removed):

https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/b1ay90o1/